# Flow optimizations for calling

Tags: twilio

my company buy twilio license. Now i'm trying to configure a simple flow with twilio studio as follow:

[image]

the logic is, Azure alert trigger and call twilio number and after twilio with make outgoing call widget "call_user_1" have to call my number and it works. A problem is that it call me 3 times consecutive, in total around 30 second for all of three call(the last call duration is around a couple of second, the other 2 around 10-15 second each).

The other problem is with the second widget, transitions from first to second doesn't work. If i no answer it always call my colleague number added in second widget a the same time of my number.

All setting are default i only change on following json the phone number:

```
    {
  "description": "Reperibilità_Infra_2",
  "states": [
    {
      "name": "Trigger",
      "type": "trigger",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "incomingMessage"
        },
        {
          "next": "call_user_1",
          "event": "incomingCall"
        },
        {
          "event": "incomingRequest"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": 40,
          "y": -190
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "call_user_1",
      "type": "make-outgoing-call-v2",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "answered"
        },
        {
          "next": "call_user_1",
          "event": "busy"
        },
        {
          "next": "call_user_2",
          "event": "busy"
        },
        {
          "next": "call_user_2",
          "event": "noAnswer"
        },
        {
          "next": "call_user_2",
          "event": "failed"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "machine_detection_speech_threshold": "2400",
        "detect_answering_machine": false,
        "offset": {
          "x": -500,
          "y": 140
        },
        "recording_channels": "mono",
        "timeout": 60,
        "machine_detection": "Enable",
        "trim": "do-not-trim",
        "record": false,
        "machine_detection_speech_end_threshold": "1200",
        "machine_detection_timeout": "30",
        "from": "twilionumber",
        "to": "mynumber",
        "machine_detection_silence_timeout": "5000"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "call_user_2",
      "type": "make-outgoing-call-v2",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "answered"
        },
        {
          "event": "busy"
        },
        {
          "event": "noAnswer"
        },
        {
          "event": "failed"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "machine_detection_speech_threshold": "2400",
        "detect_answering_machine": false,
        "offset": {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 420
        },
        "recording_channels": "mono",
        "timeout": 60,
        "machine_detection": "Enable",
        "trim": "do-not-trim",
        "record": false,
        "machine_detection_speech_end_threshold": "1200",
        "machine_detection_timeout": "30",
        "from": "twilio",
        "to": "mycolleaguenumber",
        "machine_detection_silence_timeout": "5000"
      }
    }
  ],
  "initial_state": "Trigger",
  "flags": {
    "allow_concurrent_calls": false
  }
}
```

there is a way to say:

- call_user_1, if i'm busy try another times on my number and if continue to be busy go ahead on the second widget;
- call_user_1 if i no answer after call, i'm busy or the call fail go ahead with the number in call_user_2;

Thanks

Comment: I don't have a full answer for you, but that busy loop back to calling the number again is going to loop or cause an error until you answer it and it is a bad idea. You should at least put a counter in between and an exit.

Comment: Hi phil. I canceled the busy loopback. Now the 3 call arrive at the same time on both numbers inserted in both widget. Is a way to optimize that? Can you make an example for my request if possible?

Comment: That seems really weird. Is something triggering the Studio flow three times? How have you set up the Azure alert trigger?

Comment: Azure trigger one time the alert and after generate the call(I think is azure alert that do this strange behavior and call 3 times). Is in twilio a way to increase timeout? 
Before to fix that i would like to setup as follow the flow:
Azure call twilio number. I would like to put a check to say, twilio call me but if i'm busy, no answer or call failed retry to call my number. if i continue to be busy, no answer etc... only after that call my colleague. (now it call at the same time both number in that two widget)
Is possible to setup in this way?

Comment: Both the Make Outgoing Call and Connect Call To widgets allow you to set the timeout in the widget settings. If you want to try your phone number twice, then your colleagues, I'd try to simplify things and place two widgets that call your number followed by one that calls your colleague. If you wanted to add more tries, or make it configurable, you could create a counter variable and use a split to see if the number of attempts to your number is over the limit and then move on to your colleagues. But I'd get it working by adding widgets by hand to start.